# Adding interactivity when using layer_points + layer_boxplot in ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

I am having trouble getting `layer_points()` and `layer_boxplot()` to work together when also wanting to add a tooltip.

```
require(ggvis)

### Example Data
mtc<-mtcars
mtc$label <- rownames(mtcars)   #unique Identifier


## Tooltip but not boxplot - works fine
mtc  %>% 
  ggvis(~cyl, ~qsec, key:= ~label) %>% 
  layer_points(size := 15) %>% 
  set_options(width = "auto") %>%
  add_tooltip(function(data) data$label)
})
```

[image]

```
## No tooltip - boxplot + points  - works fine
mtc  %>% 
  ggvis(~cyl, ~qsec) %>% 
  layer_points(size := 15) %>% 
  layer_boxplots(size := 0)   %>%
  set_options(width = "auto")
```

[image]

```
## Attempt at combining boxplot, points, tooltip - fails
mtc  %>% 
  ggvis(~cyl, ~qsec, key:= ~label) %>% 
  layer_points(size := 15) %>% 
  layer_boxplots(size := 0)   %>%
  set_options(width = "auto") %>%
  add_tooltip(function(data) data$label)

#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'label' not found
#Plot is produced but no interactivity
```

Does anyone have any idea how to overlay a boxplot to `layer_points()` plus a tooltip (basically to identify outliers is my aim).

An alternative answer would be how to add interactivity to the outliers automatically generated from `layers_boxplot()`

Comment: Did you have a look at [this discussion](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/309)? The error message is similar to the one you described.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if I've solved it -  they `key` has to go within `layer_points()`

```
mtc  %>% 
  ggvis(~cyl, ~qsec) %>% 
  layer_points(key:= ~label, size := 15) %>% 
  layer_boxplots(size := 0)   %>%
  set_options(width = "auto") %>%
  add_tooltip(function(data) data$label)
```